# Removing an element from an array with filter method.

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I have to do:

> You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the
>   destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all
>   elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these
>   arguments.

My code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  x = arr.filter(filterer);
  }

  function filterer(val) {
    return val !== arguments[i];
  }
  return x;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

But it doesn't work properly and returns the initial array not the filtered one. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have two issues,

- `arguments[i]` in wrong content, in a callback of the filter function,

  > ```
  > function destroyer(arr) {
  >     function filterer(val) { // <--------------------+
  >         return val !== arguments[i]; //              |
  >         //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this points to --+
  >     }
  >     for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  >         x = arr.filter(filterer);
  >     }
  >     return x;
  > }
  > ```
- no assignment of the result for further filtering.

Solution

- take a function with a closure over the test value and return a function for further testing in the filter method.
- use a variable with `arr` as start value and assign the filter result. Then return this value at the end.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {         
    function filterer(testValue) {               // take arguments[i] value
        return function (val) {                  // return function as callback
            return val !== testValue;            // use testValue instead of arguments[i]
        }
    }

    var x = arr                                  // assign arr as start value for filtering
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        x = x.filter(filterer(arguments[i]));    // use filterer with a parameter
    }
    return x;                                    // return result
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: var x = arr.slice(0) would be better so as not to alter input array

Comment: @PranavJindal `filter` is a pure function and does not alter the array it is called upon. Using `slice` is unnecessary and only adds another array creation to the overhead of this method.

Comment: @gyre filter doesn't but ```x = x.filter(filterer(arguments[i])); ``` does 

Comment: @PranavJindal, no it creates a new reference. the old array stays, please see edit.

Comment: Oops. Got it..  Thanks ☺️

Comment: @PranavJindal Objects passed by reference cannot be destroyed simply by reassigning a single reference. Only in the event that no piece of any code can reach a reference to that object does the garbage collector take action.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` scope is changed .

You want to use  `arguments[i]` inside `function filterer(val) {return val !== arguments[i];}` as it is the arguments of the parent function which is `destroyer`.

If so , use `filterer` as **arrow function**  to keep the scope of `arguments`.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  const filterer = (val) => { //  ⚠️ This is an arrow function
    return val !== arguments[i]; // ⬅️ "arguments" refers now to "destroyer()" args
  }
  for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     x = arr.filter(filterer);
  }


  return x;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

make a copy of arguments object. As Abdennour said, scope of arguments object changes for filterer.

Also, make copy of input array and keep on filtering from that array only.. otherwise your result will just be filtered for last argument.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
var copy = arguments;
var x = arr;
  for(i=1; i < copy.length; i++) {
  x = x.filter(filterer);
  }

  function filterer(val) {
    return val !== copy[i];
  }
  return x;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```